# Многопоточность Java - блок if

Tags: java

Всем привет, вопрос такой, можно ли избавиться от блока if в данном случае, чтоб выводило с такими же таймингами?

```
public class AffableThread extends Thread {
private final Object object;

AffableThread(String name, Object object) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.object = object;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (object) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(getName());

                try {
                    if(getName().equals("Понг")) {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {

                }


            object.notify();

            try {
                object.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        }
    }
}
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new Object();
        AffableThread thread1 = new AffableThread("Пинг", object);
        AffableThread thread2 = new AffableThread("Понг", object);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Избавится можно разными способами.

Я предложу такой.

```
public class AffableThread extends Thread {
private final Object object;
private long delay; 

AffableThread(String name, Object object) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.object = object;
    this.delay = name.equals("Понг") ? 5000 : 1000; 
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (object) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(getName());

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(this.delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {

                }


            object.notify();

            try {
                object.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Как я понял, нужно сделать get и set методы?
Потому что так не работает)

Comment: Нет необходимости. Щя поменяю

Comment: Странно, у меня ругается